# Obtaining Legendre polynomial form once Legendre coefficients are determined

Tags: python, numpy

I have obtained the coefficients for the Legendre polynomial that best fits my data.  Now I am needing to determine the value of that polynomial at each time-step of my data.  I need to do this so that I can subtract the fit from my data.  I have looked at the documentation for the Legendre module, and I'm not sure if I just don't understand my options or if there isn't a native tool in place for what I want.  If my data-points were evenly spaced, linspace would be a good option, but that's not the case here.  Does anyone have a suggestion for what to try?

For those who would like to demand a minimum working example of code, just use a random array, get the coefficients, and tell me from there how you would proceed.  The values themselves don't matter.  It's the technique that I'm asking about here.  Thanks.

Comment: This is a good question—I thought for sure there'd be some examples on the web that demonstrate how to use Numpy's `legendre` library, but couldn't find any. Now your question will pop up whenever any poor soul searches for an example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have a function, you can just generate a numpy array for the timepoints:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> timepoints = [1,3,7,15,16,17,19]
>>> myarray = np.array(timepoints)
>>> def mypolynomial(bins, pfinal):   #pfinal is just the estimate of the final array (i'll do quadratic)
...     a,b,c = pfinal  # obviously, for a*x^2 + b*x + c
...     return (a*bins**2) + b*bins + c
>>> mypolynomial(myarray, (1,1,0))
array([  2,  12,  56, 240, 272, 306, 380])
```

It automatically evaluates it for each timepoint is in the numpy array.

Now all you have to do is rewrite mypolynomial to go from a simple quadratic example to a proper one for a Legendre polynomial. Treat the function as if it were evaluating a float to return the value, and when called on the numpy array it will automatically evaluate it for each value.

EDIT:
Let's say I wanted to generalize this to all standard polynomials:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> timepoints = [1,3,7,15,16,17,19]
>>> myarray = np.array(timepoints)
>>> def mypolynomial(bins, pfinal):   #pfinal is just the estimate of the final array (i'll do quadratic)
>>>     hist = np.zeros((1, len(myarray)))    # define blank return
...     for i in range(len(pfinal)):
...         # fixed a typo here, was pfinal[-i] which would give -0 rather than -1, since negative indexing starts at -1, not -0
...         const = pfinal[-i-1]    # negative index to go from 0 exponent to highest exponent
...         hist += const*(bins**i)
...     return hist
>>> mypolynomial(myarray, (1,1,0))
array([  2,  12,  56, 240, 272, 306, 380])
```

EDIT2: Typo fix

EDIT3:

@Ahmed is perfect right when he states Homer's rule is good for numerical stability. The implementation here would be as follows:

```
>>> def horner(coeffs, x):
...     acc = 0
...     for c in coeffs:
...         acc = acc * x + c
...     return acc
>>> horner((1,1,0), myarray)
array([  2,  12,  56, 240, 272, 306, 380])
```

Slightly modified to keep the same argument order as before, from the code here:
http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Horner%27s_rule_for_polynomial_evaluation#Python

Comment: Is there a more elegant way than actually defining the polynomial by hand?  The only reason I ask is, if I change the degree of the polynomial in the future, I'd have to go back and change this function as well.  Otherwise, this option really has merit!  :)

Comment: You could write an anonymous function, it depends. You could dynamically define the number of parameters and then slowly refine how you define the polynomial.

I'll add an edit.

Comment: Added an edit. This would be an example of dynamically defining a mathematical function within a limited scope.

Comment: I'm going to give this a quick test, but this is probably going to be the accepted answer.  This is straightforward and transparent, two things I need at this stage of my Python career.  Thanks much!

Comment: Sorry I made a typo. Fixed that. Was trying to index -0 when it should have been -1.

Comment: Make sure you use [Horner's rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HornersRule.html) to get good numerical stability. You never want to evaluate a polynomial as `a + b*x + c*x**2 + ...`. Horner says `a + x*(b + x*(c + ...))`. [Numpy's `polyval`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval.html) uses Horner's rule of course. And [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Horner%27s_rule_for_polynomial_evaluation#Python) is as always useful.

Comment: One last related question... When I use legendre.Legendre.fit() to obtain my coefficients, they are returned as:   leg([  7.87390855e+03   2.18846710e+02  -6.30970342e-01   5.06784198e+00]).  When I try to access them like I would the elements of a typical array, I get the error message:  "TypeError: 'Legendre' object does not support indexing".  If I can't index, how am I supposed to get at the coefficients?

Comment: Within what framework are these grabbed? Print dir(variable) and then it should tell you how to return a tuple or list.

Answer (score 2):

To simplify Ahmed's example

```
In [1]: from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial, Legendre

In [2]: p = Polynomial([0.5, 0.3, 0.1])

In [3]: x = np.random.rand(10) * 10

In [4]: y = p(x)

In [5]: pfit = Legendre.fit(x, y, 2)

In [6]: plot(*pfit.linspace())
Out[6]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f815364f310>]

In [7]: plot(x, y, 'o')
Out[7]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f81535d8bd0>]
```

The Legendre functions are scaled and offset, as the data should be confined to the interval [-1, 1] to get any advantage over the usual power basis. If you want the coefficients for plain old Legendre functions

```
In [8]: pfit.convert()
Out[8]: Legendre([ 0.53333333,  0.3       ,  0.06666667], [-1.,  1.], [-1.,  1.])
```

But that isn't recommended.

Answer (score 1):

When you're using a nice library to fit polynomials, the library will in my experience usually have a function to evaluate them. So I think it *is* useful to know how you're generating these coefficients.

In the example below, I used two functions in numpy, [`legfit`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.legendre.legfit.html) and [`legval`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.legendre.legval.html) which made it trivial to both fit and evaluate the Legendre polynomials without any need to invoke Horner's rule or do the bookkeeping yourself. (Though I do use Horner's rule to generate some example data.)

Here's a complete example where I generate some sparse data from a known polynomial, fit a Legendre polynomial to it, evaluate that polynomial on a dense grid, and plot. Note that the fitting and evaluating part takes *three lines* thanks to the numpy library doing all the heavy lifting.

It produces the following figure:
[image: Legendre fitting and evaluation]

```
import numpy as np
### Setup code
def horner(coeffs, x):
    """Evaluate a polynomial at a point or array"""
    acc = 0.0
    for c in reversed(coeffs):
        acc = acc * x + c
    return acc

x = np.random.rand(10) * 10
true_coefs = [0.1, 0.3, 0.5]
y = horner(true_coefs, x)

### Fit and evaluate
legendre_coefs = np.polynomial.legendre.legfit(x, y, 2)
new_x = np.linspace(0, 10)
new_y = np.polynomial.legendre.legval(new_x, legendre_coefs)

### Plotting only
try:
    import pylab
    pylab.ion() # turn on interactive plotting
    pylab.figure()
    pylab.plot(x, y, 'o', new_x, new_y, '-')
    pylab.xlabel('x')
    pylab.ylabel('y')
    pylab.title('Fitting Legendre polynomials and evaluating them')
    pylab.legend(['original sparse data', 'fit'])
except:
    print("Can't start plots.")
```